# Azure SQL - How to skip USE statement in Azure SQL while having it work in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

I am trying to update an old script in a production installer so that it can work with both Azure SQL and SQL.
The problem is that our script is calling USE to switch the database.  On prem we are creating the database, in Azure it will already be created for us... so we are detecting its existence and moving on.  However that is where we are then calling USE to switch, for on prem.

I was hoping I could skip it like this in Azure

```
IF NOT SERVERPROPERTY('edition') = 'SQL Azure'
    USE MYDB
```

I am still getting the "USE statement is not supported to switch between databases."
The hack is to put this into a string and run it with: EXEC sp_executesql

This works for most things, but I don't think it works with the USE statement.
Is there any way I can let the Azure SQL parser skip this section, as it will never be executed?

I am open to SQL based workarounds... but I am trying to avoid rearchitecting the installer.

Comment: When you are not using Azure SQL, is the `USE` statement actually required? Assuming your scripts work the same in Azure and non-Azure SQL instances (so you hopefully aren't using cross database queries anyhow), why are you not able to just exclude the `USE` statement all together and just make sure that your connection is established with an `Initial Catalog` matching the desired database?

Comment: You should be connecting to the correct database to start with, not connecting (to `master`?) and then switching database context. If you need to create the database first, then do that in a separate connection.

Answer (score 0):

> USE statement is not supported to switch between databases

On Azure SQL Database this error only occurs when you try to 'USE' a different database.

> In Azure SQL Database, the database parameter can only refer to the
> current database. If a database other than the current database is
> provided, the USE statement does not switch between databases, and
> error code 40508 is returned.

[USE (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/use-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Similarly three-part names referencing the current database are allowed.